# Live Filtering Object Explorer in SSMS

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server, ssms

Are there any tools or extensions that all you to live filter database objects inside SQL Server Management Studio's [Object Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/object/manage-objects-by-using-object-explorer?view=sql-server-2017)?

#### Here's what Currently Exists

The Out-of-the-box functionality allows you to filter objects, but is hidden behind a modal which disrupts the user experience.  It also requires you to first navigate to the correct scope before applying filters and if you have a typo, you have to restart the whole flow

[image: SSMS 2017 Object Explorer]

#### Ideal Solution

Similar to **Solution Explorer Search** live search bar in Visual Studio Solution Explorer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>

[image: Visual Studio 2017 Live Search]

Or the [**Go To**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to?view=vs-2019) finder in Visual Studio <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

[image: Go To All]

#### Current Alternatives

The [Object Explorer Details](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/object/object-explorer-details-pane?view=sql-server-2017) page *kind of* provides this feature:

[image: Object Explorer Details]

However, this has three primary drawbacks

1. Requires a second window to open
2. Does not provide Live / [Incremental Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_search)
3. Appears to only match on whole name, so doesn't have [substring matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) or wildcards

Answer (score 1):

Here are some SSMS extensions that add searching functionality

### 1. [RedGate SQL Search](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/index)

Get results as you type.  Matches on object name and also object text.  Indexes objects for super fast search.

[image: RedGate SQL Search]

### 2. [dbForge SQL Search](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/search/)

Matches on object name and also object text.  Substring Matching. Indexed. Must hit return. Switch quickly between schema and data searches

[image: devart dbForge SQL Search]

### 3. [Apex SQL Search](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-search.aspx)

Matches on object name and also object text.  Substring Matching. Indexed. Must hit return. Switch quickly between schema and data searches

[image: Apex SQL Search]

### 4. [SQL Hunting Dog](http://www.sql-hunting-dog.com/) (2008 / 2012 / 2014 <sup>[[1]](https://github.com/bugzinga/sql-hunting-dog/issues/7)</sup>)

Super snappy, smallest visual footprint means it can easily stay docked above or below object explorer and leave file navigation to the internal tools.  No support yet for [SSMS 2017+](https://github.com/bugzinga/sql-hunting-dog/issues/7)

[image: SQL Hunting Dog]

### Honorable Mentions ($$)

5. [**SSMS Tools Pack**](https://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=5) ($30) only *data* search, not *object* search
6. [**SQL Smash**](http://www.sqlsmash.com) ($99)